# webapp-container Opens Up Browser

Tags: browser, webapps

I use [draw.io](http://draw.io) a lot, since it feels better than Libreoffice Draw itself. I use it in my browser, but I do not feel well using it in browser. So I came up with a solution to load web pages in a webkit, which is `webapp-container`.

I followed [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/web/tutorials/web-app-tutorial/) as a guide and created my desktop entry (a little bit different than documentation says) as following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=webapp-container --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https://draw.io/* https://draw.io
Name=Draw.io
Type=Application
```

It was working in [BrowserQuest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org) example very well. However, when I load it up as above, it simply opens up the browser to run it.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

You need to define `--webappUrlPatterns` well, to use subdomains, too. New is as below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=webapp-container --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https?://*draw.io/* https://draw.io
Name=Draw.io
Type=Application
```